# Can't use hash.key in a ternary if statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, ternary

I have a hash containing key value pairs, and I'm trying to use a ternary if but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<%= @positions.key? 'dashboard' %> # => true

<%= @positions.key? 'dashboard' ? 'true text' : 'no text' %> # => false
```

Am I not using the correct code? If this doesn't work is there a way to check if a hash key exists using a ternary if condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parenthesis around parameter:

```
<%= @positions.key?('dashboard') ? 'true text' : 'no text' %>
```

Comment: thanks just realised the minute I posted the question, no idea why I didn't try it before. I thought Rails didn't rely on parenthesis for parameters but I guess it matters in some cases. Thanks.